# Application keyboard shortcuts can't modify in gnome

Tags: 11.04, shortcuts

I have **gconftool** set to `/desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels true`, but can't assign or modify any application accelerators in Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration item has been moved to the `gsettings` system.  You should be able to set the new configuration value with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface can-change-accels true
```

If you prefer a graphical tool to modify these settings, try installing the `dconf-tools` package to get the `dconf-editor` tool.

Comment: Now I have in true "can-change-accels" but still can't change the acels of any program. The way I tried to change the accels is put the mouse on the menú item and press the accel.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, this does not work with Unity, see bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/610234

One can temporarily start an application with aditable menus in Unity by running it with `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=`. I.e. to start leafpad, `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= leafpad`.